# Is it possible to merge pdf created using animate package from beamer with Nitro or Acrobat Pro combine tools?

Tags: beamer, animate, combine

I was checking some animated pdfs using the animate package from beamer and then I was wondering if it is possible to merge this pdf with other pdf created without this package. I tried to get one animated pdf from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/animations/ and merge with a traditional one using the combine tool of Nitro Pro but the section where is animated got blank. Any suggestion what would be the best whey to combine them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Perhaps you could add the 'traditional one' to your [`beamer`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) presentation using [`pdfpages`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) ?

Answer (score 2):

Most tools for PDF manipualtion, such as pdftk, fail to merge PDFs containing `animate` produced animations with other PDFs.

Much of the code an animation depends upon is spread over the PDF file, such as in the PDF Catalog (which is a central object in a PDF file) and in the page object of the page containing the animation. Moreover, the PDF objects representing the animation frames are separate objects. References to these objects are collected by the JavaScript code of an animation. It is not very likely, that a (commercial) PDF tool, even the most expensive one, would be sophisticated enough to resolve all dependencies and to properly establish the relationship between them.

The only reliable way to re-use an existing animation is to copy the LaTeX code of the original (`\animategraphics`, `animateinline`) into the LaTeX source of the target document.